# Iterate properties and nested first level properties

Tags: c#, reflection

I have the following classes

```
public class Car
{
    public int CarId { get; set;}
    public string Description { get; set;}
    public Engine Engine { get; set;}
}

public class Engine
{
    public int EngineId { get; set;}
    public int Description { get; set;}
}
```

Now i want to iterate all the properties in Car and all the properties in Engine, i dont want to hardcode the property names "Car or Engine"

Example to get all properties of Car, where `obj` is instance of Car.

```
var properties = obj.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
```

But this doesnt iterate the properties of Engine.

Comment: So how do you know which types to delve deeper in and which not to?  Why shouldn't you get the properties of a `string`?

Comment: Properties and nested properties mean that i want all properties in the first class and all the properties in nested property.

Comment: That's not how you described it in your question.  In your question you stated that you only wanted it to expand out the `Engine` property.  Are you saying that you want the other properties, including the properties of the string `Description` to be expanded as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FlattenHierarchy` does not do what you think it does, and instead follows the inheritance hiearchy for static members.

If you'd like to get sub-properties for objects, you'll need to do that yourself:

```
static IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> FlattenProperties(Type type)
{
    // Assumption #1: you do not want "simple" types enumerated
    if (!type.IsClass)
        return Enumerable.Empty<PropertyInfo>();

    // Assumption #2: you want to ignore "the usual suspects"
    if (type.Namespace != null && type.Namespace.StartsWith("System"))
        return Enumerable.Empty<PropertyInfo>();

    // Assumption #3: your class hierarchy won't destroy recursion
    // Assumption #4: you simply want the PropertyInfo
    return type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy
                            | BindingFlags.Instance
                            | BindingFlags.Public)
               .SelectMany(pi => new[] { pi }
                              .Concat(FlattenProperties(pi.PropertyType)));
}
```

If this is used in code where you (a) know the depth of the recursion, and (b) have the means to alter the code, I'd suggest creating either a base class, interface, or attribute for these types/properties.

```
// Replace Assumptions #1 and #2 above with this:
// Assumption #5: given interface ISomething { }
if (!typeof(ISomething).IsAssignableFrom(type))
    return Enumerable.Empty<PropertyInfo>();
```

If you need the "property tree" (i.e. Assumption #4 is incorrect):

```
static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<PropertyInfo>> FlattenProperties(
    Type type,
    IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> ancestors = null)
{
    // change to Assumptions #1/#2 or #5 to yield break
    // ...

    ancestors = ancestors ?? Enumerable.Empty<PropertyInfo>();
    var properties = type.GetProperties(
                          BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy
                        | BindingFlags.Instance
                        | BindingFlags.Public);
    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        // again, Assumption #3: your class hierarchy won't destroy recursion
        // Assumption #6: you actually want the initial nested property too
        yield return ancestors.Concat(new[] { property });
        foreach (var nested in FlattenProperties(
            property.PropertyType, 
            ancestors.Concat(new [] { property })))
        {
            yield return nested;
        }
    }
}
```

Which, in the second case, produces output similar to:

```
// foreach (var tree in FlattenProperties(typeof(Car)))
// {
// Console.WriteLine("{0}", String.Join(".", tree.Select(pi => pi.Name)));
// }
CarId
Description
Engine
Engine.EngineId
Engine.Description
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You've to repeat the same for all properties of a type to get nested properties.

```
var properties = obj.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
foreach(var pi in properties)
{
    var nestedProperties = pi.PropertyType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just iterate through the properties of each property's [`PropertyType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.propertytype.aspx), just as you've done to get the first-level properties.

Here's a quick and dirty example using Linq:

```
var properties =
    from p1 in obj.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
    from p2 in p1.PropertyType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public).DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new { OuterProperty = p1, InnerProperty = p2 };

foreach(var prop in properties)
{
    Console.WriteLine(prop.OuterProperty.Name + (prop.InnerProperty != null ? "." + prop.InnerProperty.Name : ""));
}
```

Produces the output:

```
CarId
Description.Chars
Description.Length
Engine.EngineId
Engine.Description
```

---

You might want to only evaluate classes in a given namespace (so you don't end up capturing the `Length` property of `Description`, for example):

```
var properties =
    from p1 in obj.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
    from p2 in p1.PropertyType.Namespace == "MyNamespace" 
        ? p1.PropertyType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public).DefaultIfEmpty()
        : new PropertyInfo[] { null }
    select new { OuterProperty = p1, InnerProperty = p2 };
```

Produces the output:

```
CarId
Description
Engine.EngineId
Engine.Description
```

Or perhaps more elegantly if you define a certain attribute to mark the properties you want to traverse:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class TraversableAttribute: Attribute { }

public class Car
{
    public int CarId { get; set;}
    public string Description { get; set;}
    [Traversable]
    public Engine Engine { get; set;}
}

...

var properties =
    from p1 in obj.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
    from p2 in p1.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TraversableAttribute), true).Length > 0
        ? p1.PropertyType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public).DefaultIfEmpty()
        : new PropertyInfo[] { null }
    select new { OuterProperty = p1, InnerProperty = p2 };
```

This will produce the same output as the previous example.

Comment: 1) What if the depth is more than just 2?  If `Engine` has a complex type as a property this doesn't get it's properties 2) this gets the properties of the strings, which it shouldn't, based on the OP's requirements.

Comment: +1, and for the case with N-levels of nesting they can turn this into a recursive form.

Comment: @Servy 1) The question's title is about "nested first level properties" 2) yes it gets properties of built-in types as well, but I suppose you can use can simply filter those out of the second call to `GetProperties`.

Comment: @p.s.w.g 1) fair enough 2) How?  How do you know which should be filtered and which not?  In my mind that's the hardest part about this question, so no answer could be complete if it omits it.

Comment: @Servy I'm guessing these classes are defined in a certain domain namespace, so filtering on that might by one option. Another might by using attributes to explicitly decorate the properties OP wants to traverse. I've provided examples of both.

Comment: Downvote removed, as those are plausible options, although until the OP actually specifies the business rules for what they actually want, the question fundamentally can't be answered; you're still just guessing.

Comment: @Servy That's a fair point. I have a feeling that OP doesn't actually have any clear business rules ATM and is just looking for some options.

Comment: @p.s.w.g Or he does have strict business rules and he just hasn't told them to us, or he hasn't even thought about it and once he does he'll come up with some concrete rules, or who knows what else.  Fundamentally, it's a decision that he needs to make before the question can be answered, as it's written.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the properties from the original class and its 1st lower hierarchy level, then you could just create the following attribute like so.

```
public class BrowsableAttribute : Attribute { }
```

Now simply decorate the classes you want to browse for properties, in your case, that would be the Engine class.

```
[Browsable]
class Engine
{
    public int EngineId { get; set; }
    public int Description { get; set; }
}
```

Now all you need to do is use the following extension method.

```
public static class TypeExtensions
{
    public static void BrowseProperties(this Type type)
    {
        var h1 = typeof(Car).GetProperties().ToList();            
        var h2 = h1.Where(x => x.PropertyType.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<BrowsableAttribute>().Any());                       

        h2.ToList().ForEach(x => h1.AddRange(x.PropertyType.GetProperties()));
        h1.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.Name));
    }
}
```

Which will produce the desired result. To see this, execute the following lines of code.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        typeof(Engine).BrowseProperties();

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```